# qt virtual keyboard disable on certain TextInputs

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols2, qtvirtualkeyboard

here is example code

```
TextField {
id:needKeyboard
}

TextField {
id:dontNeedKeyboard
}
```

if i focus to every above `TextFields` virtual keyboard will shown to me
I want to disable qt virtual keyboard popup on certain `TextField` or `TextInput`, how is it possible?

Comment: Tried enabled: false?

Comment: i don't want to disable TextField!